# Why the function names and parameter names are changed when I use in polkadot api?

Tags: polkadot-js, ink

I defined the ink! method and struct like this:

```
#[derive(SpreadAllocate, PackedLayout, SpreadLayout, Clone, Decode, Encode)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(Debug, scale_info::TypeInfo, StorageLayout))]
pub struct ShowTest{
    test_id: u8,
}

//...

#[ink(message)]
pub fn show_test_add(&mut self, v: ShowTest) {
}
```

After I deployed the contract to the local contract-test chain, I found the method name `show_test_add` became `showTestAdd` and field name `test_id` became `testId`.

And it was the same when I used polkadot api in JS, I don't know why.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Polkadot.js transforms contract message names to `camelCase` for consistency across its packages and alignment with JavaScript common practice.

https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api-contract/FAQ#why-is-there-a-snake_case-vs-camelcase-difference